# Best FUNCTION to search for a character inside a string sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best FUNCTION to search for a character inside a string sql?

I've been trying to search if there exists a character inside a fixed string.

For example I have:

```
1OF2. 040713 08:07 AM
```

And I want to know if there is a `'.'` inside the string.

Comment: Have you tried `LIKE`?

Comment: Please don't use subjective wording in your questions if you want good responses.  It's best to avoid 'what is the best...'.

Answer (score 6):

Use `like`:

```
select col like '%.%'
```

It is standard SQL and SQL Server has some good optimizations built into the query engine to handle it.

EDIT (in response to a comment):

Getting the first part of the string is a bit different.  In that case:

```
select (case when col like '%.%' then left(col, charindex('.', col) - 1)
             else col
        end)
```

Comment: "has some good optimizations" --- that's interesting. What kind of optimizations?

Comment: I want to remove the left part of the '.' For example `1OF2. 040713 08:07 AM` and I want `040713 08:07 AM`

Comment: For instance, if you have `xxx%`, then it knows to do an index lookup on the prefix.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: every DB does that I suppose

Comment: @Aj De Guzman: so why didn't you ask it in the original question but now?!?!?!

Comment: @GordonLinoff

Can you cite an example of what you're trying to say? I'm a newbie in MS SQL.

Comment: @zerkms

I've been trying this:

`DECLARE @mySample varchar(255)
SET @mySample = '1OF2. 040713 08:07 AM'
(SELECT convert(datetime, (STUFF(STUFF(((SUBSTRING(@mySample,CHARINDEX('.',@mySample,1)+2, LEN (@mySample)))),3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'))))`

Comment: @zerkms all i want to do is to convert the string `'1OF2. 040713 08:07 AM'` into datetime. but before that, i want to remove the `1OF2` thing for better conversion

Comment: @zerkms

No. I did try what i pasted a while ago. I did search about `STUFF` SQL `CHARINDEX` etc. I'm purely a newbie with these things.

Answer (score 4):

CHARINDEX is also available.  Use CHARINDEX and compare against 0 (not found).  For example:

```
SELECT *
WHEN CHARINDEX('.',field) > 0
```

Comment: I tested charindex vs like. Like worked faster on 6 mil rows. Can you document this claim ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Good to know -- thinking on it, I last tested it quite a while back.  It seems my observations from then are no longer valid, answer edited.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - I'd be interested to know if it was faster when you are doing both like in Gorden's answer `case when col like '%.%' the left(col, charindex('.', col) - 1) else col end` my guess is this is faster `case when charindex('.', col) > 0 then left(col, charindex('.', col) - 1) else col end`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want 040713 08:07AM

```
declare @strings varchar(50)

select @strings ='1OF2. 040713 08:07 AM'

select (case when @strings like'%.%' then 
right(@strings, charindex('.', @strings) +10)     else @strings end)
```